# How can I get DataBindings to be two-way (not just when the UI changes, but when a property is changed in code)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I'm having trouble using `DataBindings` in a Windows Form / User Control.  For example:

Create a windows form, place a single text-box on it & place two buttons on it.  The code behind the form is:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Form1
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub

    Private mSomeProperty As String

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("text", Me, "SomeProperty", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    End Sub


    Public Property SomeProperty() As String
        Get
            Return mSomeProperty
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mSomeProperty = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProperty")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox(Me.SomeProperty)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.SomeProperty = "Set in code - see it on the UI?"
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you type something into the text box & press `Button1`, you'll get a message box with the text of the property in it.  If, however, you press `Button2` (which sets the property in code) and then press `Button1` again, you'll see that while the property was indeed set in the code, the text box doesn't reflect the change.

What am I missing, please!?

**EDIT**: Updated the code to provide the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  This now works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

There are lots of [questions](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-gb%3AIE-SearchBox&q=INotifyPropertyChanged+stackoverflow&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) on this that may get you started if MSDN does not help you.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` did the trick, thank you!  Updating the code (above) to reflect the change!  Awesome!